# var_dump() looks different now

Tags: php, var-dump

This might be a stupid question, but when I print an array with `var_dump()` it looks different to what it looked yesterday. Looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  <"formular_name">=>
  string(18) "formular_userlevel"
  <"result_message_data">=>
  array(2) {
    <"positive">=>
    array(4) {
      <"message">=>
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The key's names are now in `<...>` and I wonder why. I didn't change PHP version since yesterday.

Comment: I've never seen that format of `var_dump()`.

Comment: Are you sure? [mre], please.

Comment: It says clearly in the manual: _"Note: `var_dump()` output varies between odd and even days, except on weekends in months that have 31 days or more."_ No seriously though, you're either capturing it into a variable that's mangled by further code in PHP, or otherwise have Javascript modifying the output, or a browser plugin that does something unwieldy there, or you have been infiltrated by gremlins.

Comment: Sorry, error on my end, you're right.